# How to avoid Registering a service in startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

In asp.net core we have to register service in order to use it but when services increases what we have to do?
just like the code below i just have ***ShopService*** what if i have more then 50 services.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    services.AddDbContext<SGAContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SGAContext")));
    services.AddScoped<DbContext, SGAContext>();
    services.AddScoped<IShopService, ShopService>();
}
```

What is the best way to minimize this situation.

Comment: To look at this a different way, what's the problem with doing this is you have more than 50 services?

Comment: You might be able to register then using reflection using a given namespace and some naming conventions but I doubt it is worth the effort compared to just write them out in code.

Comment: @Sean ConfigureServices then have more then 50 Registrations i have to minimize it in a way that services are registered but not visible in configureservices i just want to know if any dependencyInjections or any other way to minimize it..

Comment: @MuhammadRehan move the bulky registrations into extension methods. There is no avoiding the registration (other than auto registering). The services must get registered.

Comment: @Nkosi how to auto register a service please provide some example or any links

Comment: I only mentioned it because some 3rd party containers have that functionality. the Default Core DI does not.

Comment: @Sean the problem is that each service type added to the project has to be added to the container manually. That is boring sometimes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your services using certain criteria and reflection, like below:

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddScopedImplementations<T>(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var types = typeof(T).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(_ => !_.IsAbstract && _.IsClass && typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(_));

    foreach (var t in types)
        services.AddScoped(t);

    return services;
}
```

The idea of `AddScopedImplementations` method is to add all types that are implementing certain interface

I'm scanning the same assembly that has interface implemented within.

Then to get all types that implement interface `Startup.ConfigureServices` can be modified like

```cs
services.AddScopedImplementations<IConverterToDb>();
services.AddScopedImplementations<IMapperLink>();
```

It scans assembly that has `IConverterToDb` interface and registers all `IConverterToDb` implementations that are not abstract

You can use the same approach with interface-type registrations, like empty `IScopedServiceToBeAdded` or mark your service types with attribute to implement automatic `services.AddScoped<IShopService, ShopService>()` registrations

```
public interface IShopService : IAutoRegistration
{}
public interface ShopService : IShopService
{}
```

then you can scan for all interfaces derived from `IAutoRegistration` (like `IShopService` and use this list to find types that implement derived interfaces `ShopService`

then you can put found interface - class pairs to the `services.AddScoped(tinterface, tclass)`